# Provision custom AMI on EC2 via PHP-SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Been trying to deploy a custom AMI *that has startup daemon in them and custom packages) I have my AMI number/id. So am doing:

```
$result = $ec2Client->runInstances(array(
    'ImageId'        => $privateID, // This is my private AMI number
     'Region' => 'us-west-2', // EDITED
    'MinCount'       => 1,
    'MaxCount'       => 1,
    'InstanceType'   => $InstanceType, 
    'KeyName'        => $keyPairName,
    'SourceSecurityGroupName' => $securityGroupName,
    'SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId' => $myID,
    'UserData'       => $serverID //user-data
));
```

It says that the AMI does not exist, my guess is it is because it is private (and I want to keep it private). I tried looking at the EC2 class and could not find how to use a private AMI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html

I based this code of this blog: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/TxMLFLE50WUAMR/Provision-an-Amazon-EC2-Instance-with-PHP

EDIT: ERROR:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\Ec2\Exception\Ec2Exception' with message 'Error executing "RunInstances" on "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidAMIID.NotFound</Code><Message>The image id  (truncated...)
 InvalidAMIID.NotFound (client): The image id '[ami-b35db1d3]' does not exist - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidAMIID.NotFound</Code><Message>The image id '[ami-b35db1d3]' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>51d03326-47da-422a-ba21-404614fd1c1b</RequestID></Response>'
```

Weird it is looking at us-east-1 when my acocunt is setup at region us-west2 (a-b-c)

Comment: saw the error, could you try my second solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need point out the `region` as well.

```
'region'  => '<region name>'
```

Or could you connect aws with nominate region as below?

```
$client = Ec2Client::factory(array(
    'profile' => '<profile in your aws credentials file>',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2'
));
```

Comment: Added: 'Region'        => 'us-west-2a'; Still same problem

Comment: `us-west-2a` is available zone (AZ), `us-west-2` is region

Comment: I did change it to us-west-2 - Getting the same error. Tried Region and region (no capital R)

Comment: Could you please paste the error in your question? and don't forget to add `,` in end of line if it is not the last line.